# Excel VBA, Entering Formula in Table Only Specific Row, Not Entire Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA in Excel to enter a formula in a specific cell within a table, but don't want the entire column to get this formula.

When doing it manually, Excel gives me the option to 'Undo Calculated Column', but not when it's done through code.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim url As String
url="https://example.com/myurl"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PO Info").Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = "=Hyperlink(""" & url & """,""Supplier Portal"")"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything of use here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753563/add-modify-delete-calculated-column-formula-in-excel-listobject-table-via-vba

Comment: @QHarr Thanks me for pointing me there, is helpful indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
```

Comment: added this line before my code, entered my formula code, then used again this line with =True, works wonders!
Thanks much.